# What does it mean "reject it who will"?

Tags: grammar

The following passage is from *Les Misérables* by Victor Hugo translated by Charles E. Wilbour.

> This materialism is an excellent thing, and truly marvellous; reject it who will.
>   Ah! when one has it, he is a dupe no more; he does not stupidly allow himself
>   to be exiled like Cato, or stoned like Stephen, or burnt alive like Joan of Arc.
>   Those who have succeeded in procuring this admirable materialism have the happiness
>   of feeling that they are irresponsible, and of thinking that they can devour everything
>   in quietness — places, sinecures, honours, power rightly or wrongly acquired,
>   lucrative recantations, useful treasons, savoury capitulations of conscience,
>   and that they will enter their graves with their digestion completed.

I wonder what the grammatical structure of the sentence "reject it who will" is and what it means.

Comment: I think it's a rather dated / clunky / literary translation. But ***reject it who will*** here is a highly stylised way of saying ***regardless of the fact that some [possibly important] people might reject it***.

Answer (score 4):

The French is this ([book I, chaper 8](http://www.miserables.fr/tome-1/livre-1/chapitre-8)):

> Voilà parler! s'écria-t-il. L'excellente chose, et vraiment merveilleuse, que ce matérialisme-là! **Ne l'a pas qui veut.** Ah! quand on l'a, on n'est plus dupe; on ne se laisse pas bêtement exiler comme Caton, ni lapider comme Étienne, ni brûler vif comme Jeanne d'Arc.

I would probably translate this as, "whoever wants, does not have it", which presumably means, "whoever does not want to have it, does not have it", i.e. "whoever doesn't want materialism, can choose not to have it".

The English is clearer to me. *Reject* is either an **imperative** (probably of the third person singular) or a **subjunctive** of the third person singular, meaning "let he reject". *Who will* is a **relative clause** without an explicit antecedent, meaning "whoever wants to [reject it]". The relative clause is (in apposition to) the **subject** of *reject*:

> Let whoever wants to reject materialism reject it.

This is presumably a way to say "you can reject it if you want to, but you'd be crazy if you did".

Comment: How about interpreting it as follows?

Though it might reject one who wants it.

Comment: I would say it means something more like "Whosoever may reject it, materialism is nevertheless an excellent choice."

Comment: @Robusto: Yeah that's what I meant by "you can reject it if you want to, but you'd be crazy if you did".

Comment: @ivanhoescott: I don't think that is possible: the *though* reading would at the very least require a main clause; and, more importantly, that would not be a valid translation of the French, it would mean something else.

Answer (score 2):

I don't entirely agree with the previous response's translation of the original French text.

> "L’évêque battit des mains.
>
> Voilà parler! s'écria-t-il. L'excellente chose, et vraiment merveilleuse, que ce matérialisme-là! **Ne l'a pas qui veut.** Ah! quand on l'a, on n'est plus dupe; on ne se laisse pas bêtement exiler comme Caton, ni lapider comme Étienne, ni brûler vif comme Jeanne d'Arc."

The whole tirade is dripping with sarcasm, as the bishop speaking here is calling out a rich man on his selfishness and lack of religion. He therefore pretends to admire the mindset of the man, who basically says he doesn't need to believe in God because he's got money and prefers to leaves all that rubbish to poor people.

"Ne l'a pas qui veut", refering to the man's materialism, means not everyone is 'lucky enough' to have that trait, and feeling this way is **"not given to just anyone who wishes to"**.

This is very much a covert reproach, as the bishop does not approve of said materialism and *wealth-puts-me-above-everyone-including-God* mentality. He therefore pretends he wishes he could be like the man (which would make his life much easier, as it would have Joan of Ark's, et cetera), but can't because his darn humanity is getting in the way.

"Reject it who will" kinda leans into the sarcasm, but I don't find it super faithful to the original meaning, as it implies it *isn't* hard to be unfeeling and materialistic, which negates the bishop's point.

Answer (score 0):

It is a form of the subjunctive.

In your text the meaning is, "I think it's excellent and marvelous, and don't care that there may be people who reject it."

Let them reject it, who will (reject it). I think it's marvelous.